# How to iterate through Pandas DataFrame while considering a subset of rows

Tags: python, pandas

consider a DataFrame like this:

```
size = 10
d = {
    'id': np.random.randint(1, 10, size),
    'value': np.random.randint(10, 100, size)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Now for each row I'm counting how many previous other rows have the same id
df['others_count'] = df.groupby(['id']).cumcount()+1
```

Which produces something like this:

```
   id  value  others_count
0   3     76             1
1   4     12             1
2   1     96             1
3   6     33             1
4   4     49             2
5   8     72             1
6   8     68             2
7   7     78             1
8   9     99             1
9   1     66             2
```

For the rows which share their `id` with at least another row (in my example 4, 6 and 9), I have to add another column, which contains the average of the `value` column for all the rows *above* belonging to that id.

I've come with this solution which is fairly inefficient and I suspect also flawed somehow:

```
for row in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if df['id'][row] > 1:
        address = df['id'][row]
        others = df['others_count'][row]
        df.loc[row, 'value_estimated'] = df.loc[(df['id']==address)&(df['others_count']<others), 'value'].mean()
```

Which gives this output:

```
   id  value  others_count  value_estimated
0   3     76             1              NaN
1   4     12             1              NaN
2   1     96             1              NaN
3   6     33             1              NaN
4   4     49             2             12.0
5   8     72             1              NaN
6   8     68             2             72.0
7   7     78             1              NaN
8   9     99             1              NaN
9   1     66             2              NaN
```

Which is correct for the rows number 4 and 8 but not for the very last row, for which the value_estimated should be 96.

Do you have a better solution for this?

Comment: If you are taking the average of values with same id, shouldn't it be 30.5 for id 4 and similarly for others?

Comment: @NOOB the averaging algorithm should take into account only ids with others_count < than the id considered. Hence, when others_count = 2 the average is from a single number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do this using `groupby` on `id` and [`expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) `mean()` with a `shift` to shift the values 1 down.:

```
df['value_estimated']=df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: 
                                           x.expanding().mean().shift())
print(df)
```

---

```
   id  value  others_count  value_estimated
0   3     76             1              NaN
1   4     12             1              NaN
2   1     96             1              NaN
3   6     33             1              NaN
4   4     49             2             12.0
5   8     72             1              NaN
6   8     68             2             72.0
7   7     78             1              NaN
8   9     99             1              NaN
9   1     66             2             96.0
```